# Tablesorter with ajax refresh not working with more than one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm using jQueryUI tabs that has a table on each page. The tables are sorted by [Tablesorter 2.0](http://tablesorter.com).

The following code works great when I have a single table undergoing a refresh on a page. If I add a second table w/ a refresh, only the first one updates. Can someone tell me how I can get two tables to be sorted by tablesorter with ajax refreshes of the data?

The reload is run through this JS function:

```
$(function () {

   $(".tsRefresh").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        '.cbsort': { sorter: 'checkbox' },
        '.nosort': { sorter: false, parser: false }
    },
    theme : 'jui',
    headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', 
    widgets : ['saveSort', 'uitheme'],
    widgetOptions : {
        zebra   : ["odd", "even"]
    }
});

function getBjson() {

    var Tid = $('.tsRefresh').data('id');
    var Ttable = $('.tsRefresh').data('table');
    var Tbody = $('.tsRefresh').find('tbody').attr('id')
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: 'table=' + Ttable +'&id=' + Tid,
        success: function(output) {
             document.getElementById(Tbody).innerHTML = output;
             // update tablesorter cache
             $(".tsRefresh").trigger("update");         
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('#messageResponse').fadeIn(500);
            $('#messageResponse').addClass('ui-state-error ui-corner-all').removeClass('ui-highlight-error');
            $('#messageResponse').text(xhr.status + ' ' + thrownError + ': Something went wrong - check your inputs and try again.');
        }
    });

}

if( $('.tsRefresh').length) {
    var Ttime = $('.tsRefresh').data('time');
    var timer = setInterval(getBjson, Ttime);
    getBjson();
}

});
```

The following is the table code:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <fieldset>
    <table width="100%" id="issue" name="issue" class="tsRefresh" data-id="<?=$item_id?>" data-table="eq-load" data-time="10000">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bold">
                <th class="cbsort"><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> </th>
                <th>OAN/ID</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Desc</th>
                <th>Issued To</th>
                <th>SN</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="container1">         
        </tbody>
    </table>                        
    </fieldset>
</div>          
<div id="tabs-2">
    <fieldset>
    <table width="100%" id="my-load" name="my-load" class="tsRefresh" data-id="<?=$item_id?>" data-table="eq-load-me" data-time="10000">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bold">
                <th class="cbsort"><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> </th>
                <th>OAN/ID</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Desc</th>
                <th>Issued To</th>
                <th>SN</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="container2">
        </tbody>
    </table>                        
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

My PHP script (ajax.php) outputs the following to the tablesorter's table:

```
<tr class="dialog-hover" data-table="eq-load-item" data-id="<?=$item_id?>">
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="row-<?=$item_id?>" value="<?=$item_id?>"></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><a href="eq.view.php?id=<?=$item_id?>"><?=$item_oan?>-<?=$item_id?></a></td>
    <td><?=$item_cat?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><?=$item_desc?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><?=$issue_name?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><?=$item_serial?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You are going to have to put a loop in somewhere; `$('.tsRefresh')` will return the tables to loop over.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what to loop. Everything in the PHP script is generated by a while loop (and the output for both tables is the same, except the data itself). Am I not able to call this JS function more than once on a page?

Comment: No PHP needs changing, just js.  Re-arrange the code so `getBjson()` is called per table (via a loop) and not just for the first table.